# Delete the newly created OpenLayers string line

Tags: polygon, openlayers, line, linestring, delete

Create line strings to display the size of the sides of a polygon when selected by the user.

Here you have code:

```
var array_coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

for (var o = 0; o < array_coordinates[0].length - 1; o++) {
    var point = array_coordinates[0][o];


    PointA = array_coordinates[0][o];
    PointB = array_coordinates[0][o + 1];


    var dist = calc_dist(PointA, PointB);
    var formated_dist = format_dist(dist);

    var coordinates = [PointA, PointB];
    var line = new ol.geom.LineString([PointA, PointB]);
    dist = line.getLength();




    var line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'black'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 10
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
            padding: [30, 30, 30, 30],
            placement: 'center',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'black',
                width: 42
            })
        })
    });

    var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
                name: 'line'
            })]
        }),
    });

    dist = dist.toFixed(2);
    var data = dist + " m";


    line_stile.getText().setText(data);
    layerLines.setStyle(line_stile);

    map.addLayer(layerLines);



}
```

But I would like when the user clicks on another polygon to uncheck / delete the previously created strings on the previously selected polygon

Explanation:

By clicking the user selects a terrain on the map when he selects another terrain different from the first one and I would like to be able to delete the lines with the size of the thickness from the first selected polygon.

[image]

Here I can't give a solution at all :(

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what exactly do you mean by "previously created strings".

Comment: Explanation:

By clicking the user selects a terrain on the map when he selects another terrain different from the first one and I would like to be able to delete the lines with the size of the thickness from the first selected polygon.

Comment: So you just want to remove/hide text describing polygon dimensions?

Comment: No, i want to delete line and text.

Comment: Then just set style back do default: `layerLines.setStyle()`.

Comment: I understand, but where do I put it? Because if I put it before or after it will be undefined or delete everything it did

Comment: I tried like this:
if (layerLines) { layerLines.setStyle ();}
before: var array_coordinates but does not work :(

Comment: Sorry, wrong advice. Only now I realized you are creating new layer just to show selected polygon, so you just hide this layer with `layerLines.setVisible(false)` or remove it from the map with `map.removeLayer(layerLines)`. But be aware this with this logic you'll create new layer each time polygon will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to delete this layer before instanciate the new line.
To do so you can add a name to your layer like this :

```
    var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates),
            name: 'line'
        })]
    }),
    name : 'line', //HERE
});
```

and maybe add a layer parser just before to remove the layer if it exists:

```
var array_coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
    if (layer && layer.get('name') === 'line') {
      map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
});
```

But like @TomazicM said, you'll create a new layer and delete it each time you are selecting a polygon

Hope it can help !

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I will follow the advice of @TomazicM with a new layer for linestring